# Подозрительное снятие голосов «за» с ответов

Tags: поддержка, голоса-за, марионетки

Два дня назад на [моем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/892196/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5/892623#892623) было 19 голосов «за». Теперь только 6. И, похоже, что такая же ситуация с другими ответами к этому вопросу. Система пишет, что «участник был удалён». Неужели были удалены сразу 13 участников?

Вот я и подумал, может какая-то ошибка в системе? Мало ли…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

За два дня удалено 20 учеток, принадлежащих 4 (или 3) участникам.

[Вопрос про спиральный обход массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/892196/), к сожалению, оказался стартовым вопросом сразу для нескольких марионеток. Такие дела.

Comment: что значит "стартовым вопросом"? и в каком смысле "марионетки"?

Comment: @Anatol это значит, что на нем была обнаружена активность по накрутке голосов при помощи нескольких аккаунтов.

Answer (score 6):

Обратите внимание на профиль автора вопроса.

Его учётная запись заблокирована на год за накрутки.

Видимо, была целая ферма клонов.

Comment: Уже удалена учетка, видимо живых людей оказалось еще меньше :D

Comment: @АндрейNOP там еще и ответы есть от ныне удаленных участников. А [тут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xlbb.jpg) возможно вовсе диалог клонов :)